# Makefile warning: Warning: File `main.cpp' has modification time 2.1e+04 s in the future

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a working `Makefile`, but there is a warning that I couldn't fix.

```
#Use the g++ compiler
CC = g++

# Compiler flags:
#   -Wall (most warnings enabled)
#   -g (for debugging with gdb)
CFLAGS = -Wall

# Executable name:
TARGET = deque_adt

all: main.o deque_adt.o deque_adt

$(TARGET): main.o deque_adt.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.o deque_adt.o -o $(TARGET)

main.o: main.cpp deque_adt.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -c

deque_adt.o: deque_adt.cpp deque_adt.h
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) deque_adt.cpp -c

clean:
    rm *.o *~ $(TARGET)
```

error:

```
make: Warning: File `main.cpp' has modification time 2.1e+04 s in the future
g++ -Wall main.cpp -c
g++  -Wall deque_adt.cpp -c
g++ -Wall main.o deque_adt.o -o deque_adt
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

Can someone help me out to figure out the problem? I have tried to switch between the elements but it still gives the same warning.

Comment: This happens when you copy build outputs between two computers, and the clocks on those computers do not agree.  `make clean` ought to force regeneration of all files using the local clock, and after that you shouldn't see the issue again... unless your computer clock is badly broken.

Comment: What is the modification time on your file? That error is from make (not gcc) and is telling you that your files modification time is in the future (which make doesn't like much because it confuses it).

Comment: make clean will do nothing to fix the modification time of a non-generated .cpp file.

Comment: Oh, it's worrying about a source file?  `touch` should solve that, but the cause is the same -- copying between computers whose clocks are out of agreement.

Comment: It worked because that file's modification timestamp is now no longer in the future. Adjusting the modification timestamp on that file would also have worked.

Answer (score 65):

To expand on Ben Voigt's answer:

```
find /your/dir -type f -exec touch {} +
```

will update the timestamp on all files in the directory. You can then `make clean && make` again.

Comment: This may be tremendous overkill for the problem at hand though. This is rather the nuclear option.

Comment: @EtanReisner Not at all! This is in fact the cheapest option. With the touching and making of three source files, it'll amount to maybe two CPU seconds and ten human seconds.

Comment: Your find is calling `stat` on each file in the directory and then running touch on them all. Running touch on a single file manually is definitely faster than that. Your solution also only gets worse and worse as the project gets larger relative to the count of files that have the wrong timestamp.

Comment: @EtanReisner Are you arguing that the project is half built and that it's worth taking advantage of that, or that doing 20 extra syscalls is worth avoiding?

Comment: Yes. make is going to stat all the files anyway so having find do it isn't really going to hurt much but there's also no reason to have find do that (and then modify every single file) if there's only one file that is actually problematic. If you have a lot of files that are triggering this and don't want to manually do them all individually this works just fine (hence my "nuclear option") comment. But the question, as asked, was about a single file and running this command to fix the modification time of a single file is tremendously excessive.

Comment: "So, then let's go nuclear" is the only option that worked for me however.

Comment: "nuclear" is fine untill it works and it worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 9):

check your computer time. I had the same problem and the root cause was my computer time was in the past - when I update it, it was work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

That message is usually an indication that some of your files have modification times later than the current system time.

Chech if your system time is in the past. Example:

> $ date

If so You have several ways to fix this. the easier one is to install an ntp server:

> apt install ntp

Or

> yum install ntp

Or ...

Regarding of your operating system (Ubuntu, Centos, ...etc)

Answer (score 0):

just set your system date:

example

```
date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, did the below approach on `Ubuntu 20.04` and it worked for me.

```
touch main_.cpp
cp main.cpp main_.cpp
rm main.cpp
mv main_.cpp main.cpp
```